# subdomain redirection 301 is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am using .htaccess code for 301 redirection my subdomain to domain. And also using `domain.php?id=123` and need to redirect it into the domain name. My codes are below.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain.com/dom.php?id=12$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But when I trying to do this, i got an error like, it redirect to `http://www.domain.com/?id=12` page

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match `REQUEST_URI` and `QUERY_STRING` using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$
RewriteRule ^dom\.php$ /? [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will redirect `http://www.domain.com/dom.php?id=12` to `http://www.domain.com/`.

Or to redirect any `http://www.domain.com/dom.php?id=<number>`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=\d+$
RewriteRule ^dom\.php$ /? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I got this one, but it redirect to the `domain.com/dom?id=123`, but I need to redirect this on the root, domain.com